# Using [clock format] through TKinter changes how proc returns ""

Tags: python, tkinter, type-conversion, tcl

I am using TKinter to access an existing Tcl library from Python. One of the Tcl procs looks up values in a list and returns "" if the value is not found. The Python code sees the return value as unicode and checks to see if it is equal to "". This works perfectly until a call to [clock format] is made in the Tcl code. After that, the Python code sees the return value as a tuple. I can add some extra logic to the Python code to handle this, but is seems like there is some larger issue going on that might have other effect.

Sample Python program:

```
import Tkinter

_tclsh = Tkinter.Tcl()

_tclsh.eval('proc returnBlank { } { return "" }')
_tclsh.eval('proc returnNotBlank { } { return "not blank" }')

print "Before calling clock"
_tclsh.eval('set shouldBeBlank [returnBlank]')
shouldBeBlank = _tclsh.getvar('shouldBeBlank')
print "shouldBeBlank is ", shouldBeBlank, " with type ", type(shouldBeBlank)

_tclsh.eval('set shouldNotBeBlank [returnNotBlank]')
shouldNotBeBlank = _tclsh.getvar('shouldNotBeBlank')
print "shouldNotBeBlank is ", shouldNotBeBlank, " with type ", type(shouldNotBeBlank)

print "\nCalling [clock seconds]"
_tclsh.eval('puts [clock seconds]')
_tclsh.eval('set shouldBeBlank [returnBlank]')
shouldBeBlank = _tclsh.getvar('shouldBeBlank')
print "shouldBeBlank is ", shouldBeBlank, " with type ", type(shouldBeBlank)

_tclsh.eval('set shouldNotBeBlank [returnNotBlank]')
shouldNotBeBlank = _tclsh.getvar('shouldNotBeBlank')
print "shouldNotBeBlank is ", shouldNotBeBlank, " with type ", type(shouldNotBeBlank)

print "\nCalling [clock format [clock seconds]]"
_tclsh.eval('puts [clock format [clock seconds]]')
_tclsh.eval('set shouldBeBlank [returnBlank]')
shouldBeBlank = _tclsh.getvar('shouldBeBlank')
print "shouldBeBlank is ", shouldBeBlank, " with type ", type(shouldBeBlank)

_tclsh.eval('set shouldNotBeBlank [returnNotBlank]')
shouldNotBeBlank = _tclsh.getvar('shouldNotBeBlank')
print "shouldNotBeBlank is ", shouldNotBeBlank, " with type ", type(shouldNotBeBlank)
```

The resulting output is:

```
Before calling clock
shouldBeBlank is    with type  <type 'unicode'>
shouldNotBeBlank is  not blank  with type  <type 'str'>

Calling [clock seconds]
1431623835
shouldBeBlank is    with type  <type 'unicode'>
shouldNotBeBlank is  not blank  with type  <type 'str'>

Calling [clock format [clock seconds]]
Thu May 14 13:17:15 EDT 2015
shouldBeBlank is  ()  with type  <type 'tuple'>
shouldNotBeBlank is  not blank  with type  <type 'str'>
```

As you can see, only the empty string is affected and calling [clock] does not cause the issue; only [clock format].

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have tried different ways to return the empty string, but they did not affect the output. I tried:

```
_tclsh.eval('proc returnBlank { } { return }')
_tclsh.eval('proc returnBlank { } { return {} }')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with the way Tkinter guesses the type of a string.

In Tcl there simply is no meaningful difference between an empty list or an empty string, so the bytecode compiler can change the internal types at will, just what is most convenient for Tcl in that case.

Tcl uses a `Tcl_Obj` structure in the C implementation which can hold at most two type informations at once (one is always string, the other is the current view of the Tcl interpreter, depending on last usage of the object).

So, if some code tries to 'guess' a type for a Tcl object, it does the following (unreliable) trick, it looks at the internal values of the Tcl object and assumes if a type pointer is set, the object is of that type.

So watch this:

```
import Tkinter
tclsh = Tkinter.Tcl()
tclsh.eval('set x ""')
v = tclsh.getvar('x')
print type(v)
tclsh.eval('lindex $x 0')
v = tclsh.getvar('x')
print type(v)
```

First it is a 'str' and later a 'tuple'. So, this happens if you use a variable as a list, but why does it modify your procs return value?

This happens due to aggressive literal sharing when byte compiling. The empty string is such a common literal, that there is usually just one object of it (like Pythons `None` or small integers).

You can use a small trick to work around this issue, if you really need to, just force the type conversion (called 'shimmering' see http://wiki.tcl.tk/3033) explictly.

E.g. if you want to force an integer internal representation, in Tcl:

```
set x "2"
incr x 0
# X now has internal type Integer

lindex $x 0
# X now has internal type tuple

append x ""
# X now has the internal type unicode
```

And so on. It is one of the quirks when you try to map two languages type systems if they are vastly different, you see similar effects in DBAPI Layers to sqlite or when trying to call functions via xmlrpc or json.

Comment: The `append` thing to force the type to unicode is _really_ non-portable between versions. You'll find that `string replace` or `string range` are more suitable. With some caveats. We normally avoid talking about types in Tcl precisely because they're actually pretty fluid down there…

Comment: And `tcl::unsupported::representation` might help too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and excellent explanation. Based on your example above, I wrote the following Tcl code that might fix the problem (but based on @DonalFellows comments, maybe it won't. `proc returnBlank { } { set ret ""; append ret ""; return $ret }`

Comment: Updated option based on @DonalFellows comments: `proc returnBlank { } { return [string range "" 0 0]`

Comment: After making the change and doing more testing, I discovered the problem was bigger than the return value for the single call. Based on what @schlenk said, the internal type of `""` was changed from unicode to tuple. This started breaking lots of different parts of the Tcl code that expected `""` to be a string. Rather than putting lots of extra checking all over the code, I figured it would be easier to just "fix" `""` by reseting it to a string. I added `set treatEmptyAsString [string "" 0 0]` as the next line after the call to `clock format` and everything seems happy. Thank you both.